# Android - Preload an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, preload

I want my app to preload it's activity in order to make navigation more fluid.
I searched around for similar answer, but they did not answer my problem.

I am using some simple animation on click for design purpose, and i want the next activity to be displayed as soon as the animation finish (~200 to 400 ms).
Some of my activity are displayed quite fast, but other can take up to 700ms.

I want to preload all the relevant activities before the animation begin, and display them as soon as possible after the animation. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use asynctask for your processes, maybe all your process are on onCreate() method that's why it's so slow to load the activity

Comment: are you using async task to load data or everything was done on UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to load data in the UI thread. Use async task to load data.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).